Closed questions
The policy on SE is to delete closed questions that aren't salvageable, spam, illegal, too localized, etc. Only duplicates might be left there, as they serve the useful purpose of directing users to the actual question.
What I'm asking with this question is for everyone of you out there to go hunting closed questions and if you think they can be fixed, do it, if not then vote to delete. Not all of you have the reputation to do this so for those who can't vote, please flag for deletion. A moderator will immediately check that questions and act on it.
Why deleting? We don't want broken windows in our site, only nice shiny questions. :) 
How do you easily find such questions? Just type closed:1 in the search field. 
One last thing: if you fix a question, flag for reopening. If you're not sure how to edit it but you think it's salvageable then, post an answer here asking for help. 
Please note that I'll be doing this too, so if you have a closed question posted by you, make sure you fix them, if you don't want to risk them to be deleted... (It's not a menace of course.) Reputation gained/lost from deleted questions will be restored in the event of a recalc as if the question was never asked.
